# React Hooks + Socket.io

Tags: javascript, react, websocket, socket.io, jsx

Estou usando os React Hooks para uma aplicação simples, um clone do feed do Instragam. Para fazer as requisições de cada post na api, estou usando essa lógica:

```
function Feed() {
  const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
    async function getPost() {
      try {
        const response = await api.get('/posts');
        console.log(response.data);
        setPost(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        if (error) alert('Deu rium na request');
      }
    }
    getPost();
  }, []);
```

Rola muito bem, eu consigo renderizar o post percorrendo a varíavel "posts" que é meu estado dentro do componente apenas declarando um post.map dentro do meu JSX.

```
return (
    <section id="post-list">
      {posts.map(post => (
        <article key={post._id}>
          <header>
            <div className="user-info">
              <span>{post.author}</span>
              <span className="place">{post.place}</span>
            </div>
```

A coisa fica mais complexa quando eu tento aplicar o realtime com o socket.io, que é uma lib do node para websockets. Estabeleci uma função, chamada registerToSocket,

```
function registerToSocket() {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3333');
    socket.on('posts', (newPost) => {
      setPost({ posts: [newPost, ...posts] });
    });
  }
```

Que faz toda a configuração dos sockets, mas estou empacado em como aplicar isso dentro do meu useEffect, que é uma espécie do método componentDidMount das classes do React, impedindo de criar loopings infinitos e um codigo quebrado. Se alguém souber alguma solução, fico grato!

Comment: Você está colocando o `registerToSocket` dentro de algum `useEffect`? Coloque o código completo do componente...

Comment: Esse é basicamente o código de logica do componente...


`function registerToSocket() {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3333');
    socket.on('posts', (newPost) => {
      setPost({ posts: [newPost, ...posts] });
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getPost() {
      try {
        const response = await api.get('/posts');
        console.log(response.data);
        setPost(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        if (error) alert('Deu rium na request');
      }
    }
    getPost();
  }, []);`

Answer (score -1):

Já resolvei esse problema, basicamente, a funcão `registerToSocket` não precisava necessariamente estar dentro de um `useEffect` para acionar os sockets, eu basicamente estava usando uma varíavel diferente à dos emits dentro do backend. E também dentro da função, eu estava setando um novo objeto para o estado, sendo que eu só deveria passar o vetor dos novos posts e repassar todos os posts que já estão dentro do estado.

A função corrigida ficou desta maneira:

```js
function registerToSocket() {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3333');
    socket.on('post', (newPost) => {
      setPost({[newPost, ...posts] });
    });
  }
```